# Visual Studio 2015 language pack incomplete

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio in Spanish and then downloaded the English language pack. This pack seems incomplete, the most used properties have changed to English but there is still a lot of options in Spanish. I remember in VS2010 I deleted one single settings file to force VS to display fully in English. What are my options here?